# Dependency conflict resolution with different group id?

Tags: maven

Artifacts with conflicting content:

`org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.17.1-GA` && `javassist:javassist:jar:3.12.1.GA`

The former comes from Hibernate and the latter from Guava. Both end up in the final war file. The problem is that the classic conflict resolution mechanisms fail because the group id is different. So both the jars end up in the final project deliverable.

I can't just exclude Guava's dependency in the managed dependencies because the project is a multi-module. Some modules use Guava w/o Hibernate. They would miss their javassist dependency. But if I don't the "excess" artifact will pop up in the project's war file.

Is there a way to tell Maven those two dependencies are in fact two different versions of the same code ?

Comment: I'd add explicit dependency on this artifact to your project's main pom.xml and exclude it both from guava and hibernate.

Comment: @AndrewLogvinov Why not post an answer? That suggestion sounds good.

Comment: +1 for telling me where the bastards were hiding in the first line of your answer! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd stick with the following solution:

1. Add explicit dependency on `javassist` artifact in main pom.xml of your project (so that all of the child modules inherit this dependency).
2. Exclude `javassist` both from Hibernate and Guava.
3. Most important: add a comment indicating why you need `javassist` dependency :)

Comment: Why didn't I think about this myself ? Must be the headbanging ! thanks ! :-)

Comment: This helped me. Also, beware of javassist version, especially if you use generics. I was trapped in problem which I [described in my blog](http://tomaszalusky.blogspot.cz/2015/03/kam-az-muze-vest-konflikt-maven.html) (in Czech but it's obvious from attached Java code).